# How to bind value to Dropdown only once when the values are Repeated?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have some data which I am binding to a dropdown dynamically like this:

```
if (product.oPTIONS.length > 0) {
   $.each(product.oPTIONS, function (idx, options) {
         /*appending the each option to a label*/
         $("#productdetails").append('<div class="clear">');
         $("#productdetails").append('<label>' + options.OptionName + '</label>');
         if (options.values.length > 0) {
            var stringBuilder = [];
            /*Creating a select tag for the Retrieved options*/
            $("#productdetails").append('<select id="' + options.OptionName + '" onchange="getimage($(this).val())" ><option>Choose</option>');
            $.each(options.values, function (idx, values) {
            /*Binding options to the Created select tag For an Option based on option Id*/           
            $("" + "#" + options.OptionName + "").append('<option value="' + values.sku + '">' + values.OptionValue + '</option>');
        });
        stringBuilder.push('</select>');
        $("#productdetails").append(stringBuilder.join(''));
     }
     $("#productdetails").append('</div>');
   })
 }
```

Now my situation is that some of the values of a drop down may be repeated in that case only one value should be bound to the drop down.

```
 example
   Size:DropDown
     [S]
     [XXl]
     [s]
     [xl]
   Fit:DropDown
     [Slim]
     [Regular]
     [Slim]
     [AppleCut]
```

This is the case, here I want to bind only [S],[Slim] in size,Fit dropdowns only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the options to an array as they are considered for inclusion in the select, checking for their existence against that array before inclusion:

```
var optionsarray = new Array();
$.each(options.values, function (idx, values) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(values.OptionValue.toUpperCase(), optionsarray) < 0) {                            
        $("" + "#" + options.OptionName + "").append('<option value="' + values.sku + '">' + values.OptionValue + '</option>');           
    }
    optionsarray.push(values.OptionValue.toUpperCase());
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Comment: in this case only the repeated value is binded remainig all are removed

Comment: i will wait a bit..if i can get an much better answer from any one ..if i accept this i will miss that answer mate..if no one answers by tomorrow definitely your answer will be in first place...:-)